# Date format in the json output using spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am working on spring boot for creating a REST application. And I have a DTO as shown below:

```
public class Subject {

private String uid;
private String number;
private String initials;
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

And I use Spring-Hateos and the reurn type of my controller is `ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Subject>>>`. I need the date to be displayed in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Answer (score 68):

If you have Jackson integeration with your application to serialize your bean to JSON format, then you can use Jackson anotation [@JsonFormat](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) to format your date to specified format.
In your case if you need your date into `yyyy-MM-dd` format you need to specify `@JsonFormat` above your field on which you want to apply this format.

For Example :

```
public class Subject {

     private String uid;
     private String number;
     private String initials;

     @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
     private Date dateOfBirth;  

     //Other Code  

}
```

From Docs :

> annotation used for configuring details of how values of properties
>   are to be serialized.

[More Reference Doc](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I am having facing an issue here. The date displayed in the json format is 1 day less.

Comment: Please post what value you are storing and how ? from database or something else

Comment: I am retrieving the date from an soap service which is in XMLGregorianCalendar format. I have converted this into java.util.Date, and it is converted to json format. For ex: after converting XMLGregorianCalendar object to Date, it displays 2014-02-11 in the console. But in the json output it is displaying 2014-02-10.

Comment: subject.setNumber(subjectContainer.getNumber());
        subject.setInitials(subjectContainer.getInitials());
        if(subjectContainer.getDateOfBirth() != null) subject.setDateOfBirth(subjectContainer.getDateOfBirth().toGregorianCalendar().getTime());

Comment: what is the data type of `DateOfBirth` field of subjectContainer type object ?

Comment: @YagneshAgola , Does this work with Deserialization too? I tried this for a similar problem, but it is not working : I am trying to deserialize a Json response from a web service using jackson.

Comment: @bub yes its working for me also. I have used similar things in my project.

Comment: @Pramod adding `timezone` to `@JsonFormat` shall fix the problem.

Answer (score 32):

You most likely mean "yyyy-MM-dd" small latter 'm' would imply minutes section.

You should do two things

- add `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps:false` in your `application.properties` this will disable converting dates to timestamps  and instead use a ISO-8601 compliant format
- You can than customize the format by annotating the getter method of you `dateOfBirth` property with `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Hi, I am having facing an issue here. The date displayed in the json format is 1 day less.

Comment: Tested with Spring Boot 1.3.0 you do not seem to require the ```spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps``` but it is sufficient to only use the ```@JsonFormat``` annotation

Comment: Is there a way to do this with all dates, and not have to annotate one by one?

Comment: @Pramod did you find any solution for date display 1 day less

Comment: It is showing the correct date for me (springboot v.2.0.3)

Comment: Facing the same issue here too, am using spring-boot 2.1.8.RELEASE.
Date one day less.
Note: in table am just storing till date:2019-09-23 not datetime:2019-09-23 10:01:00 does this makes any difference.

Answer (score 12):

Starting from Spring Boot version 1.2.0.RELEASE , there is a property you can add to your `application.properties` to set a default date format to all of your classes `spring.jackson.date-format`.

For your date format example, you would add this line to your properties file:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

Reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: If it is a property, I believe it should be imported somewhere.
The question is Where. 
Tested - does not work if simply added to application.properties or application.yml

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the format for all dates you can add a builder customizer.  Here is an example of a bean that converts dates to ISO 8601:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.dateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());        
        }           
    };
}
```

Comment: Works great! You should add this to your AppConfig/@Configuration class

Comment: Is this still working?  new ISO8601DateFormat()) seems deprecated